# Where does numpy.ndarray's iterable behavior come from?

Tags: python, numpy

numpy's `ndarray` class is defined as

```
class ndarray(__builtin__.objects)
```

From what I can gather, `__builtin__.objects` is not an iterable type? For this reason I find this behavior surprising:

```
Arr = numpy.array('As Far As I Know'.split())
=> array(['As', 'Far', 'As', 'I', 'Know'], dtype='|S4')
print map(lambda x: x[0],Arr)
=> ['A', 'F', 'A', 'I', 'K']
```

Or does this come from the attributes of the (`list`) object that is passed to the `__init__` method of the `ndarray`? But then why cannot I not use methods like `list.reverse` on the array object, if it is internally stored as a list?

(and as a side not does anyone know any better way to apply string-operations on each element of `ndarray` objects?)

Comment: Guido lists both `map` and `lambda` as "python regrets", so I'm tending to prefer the list comprehensions eg `np.array([k[0] for k in x])`

Comment: Yes, I've followed this debate closely (he hates `reduce` and `lambda` but not necessarily `map`, to my knowledge), but `x` is a local variable using `map` and `lambda` in the example above; `k` is global in the use of a list comprehension as you've shown. I have trouble accepting list comprehensions for that reason.

Comment: @crippledlambda: In Python 3 the loop variables of list comprehensions aren't leaked to the enclosing scope any more.  If you want to avoid this leaking in Python 2, you can transform `[... for x in a]` to `list(... for x in a)`.

Comment: Right, I'd heard there was a move to not make it global and I was  not aware they implemented that in Python 3. VERY interesting illustration with converting the iterator to `list()`...!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`numpy.ndarray` defines [`__iter__()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__), which the usual (and only) mechanism to make instances of a type iterable.  Note that `numpy.ndarray` is a C extension type, but this doesn't matter for the question why it is iterable.  Both, types you define in Python and C extension types can be made iterable by defining `__iter__()`.

Comment: Ah, so it is not inherited but defined specifically for it. Check.